# How to setup a login page in angular that allow to access asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, angular, authorization

**What i have already:**
Two asp.net web applications with windows based authentication.

**What i want now:**
I want to create a login page in Angular 6 .
Consider the user click enters credentials and clicked signin on that page.

If the user is valid i should allow them to access  asp.net web application which has got windows authentication enabled on it already.

So based on the inputs i should redirect user to the particualr asp.net web applications.

If the login fails i should show some error page.

Is that possible.IF yes how could we achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ASP.Net website hosted in a different URL?

If so, once the Authentication API responds successfully, you can just bypass Angular's `router` and use `window.location = "http://your.asp.net.website.com"`. If not, show the error message and prompt for the correct credentials.

Comment: yes those ASP.Net website are hosted in IIS on different aplication servers.

Comment: So, does this answer solve your problem? Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location for further information.